# Pandas Dataframe: Filter by column value startswith int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which looks like this:

```
ID  Unit    Semester    Note    BNF
0   3537    143066.0    4010    2.3 5
1   3537    143067.0    4010    m.E.    E
2   75      113142.0    4011    5.0 5
3   3726    113142.0    4011    3.3 5
4   5693    113142.0    4011    5.0 5
```

this dataframe contains three categories. These categories are based on the values in the "Semester"-column. There are values which start with 113, 143 and 153.

Now I want to split this whole dataframe that I get three new dataframes for every categorie.

I tried to convert the column to string and work with 'startswith'.

```
mi = df[df['Unit'].apply(str)]
mi = df[df['Unit'].startswith('143')]
```

but that didn't work.

I hope someone could help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't your target meant to be the Semester and not Unit `mi = df[df['Unit'].apply(str)]`? If so, then I would suggest making a new column (or use a multi-level index) with the following approach:

```py
df["Semester_Start"] = df["Semester"].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:3])

#Take sub-sections
df[df["Semester_Start"] == "143"]
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html

Comment: no, I really need the Units but I achieved that with df["Studiengang"] = df["Unit"].apply(lambda x: str(x)[:3]). Thanks @all for helping

Comment: ```apply``` is not really good idea here. Instead try:  ```df["Studiengang"] = df["Unit"].astype("str").str[:3]```

Comment: avoid using apply whenever you can, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```py
dfs=[df.loc[df.Unit.astype(str).str.startswith(el)] for el in df.groupby(df["Unit"].astype("str").str[:3]).groups]
```

In short - you get the list of all possible first 3 digits of `Unit`.

Then You just iterate over that list in list comprehension filtering for each element using python string `startswith(...)` method.

Hope this helps!